# Overriding JTextPane to prevent auto-resizing

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, jtextpane

I'm trying to make a JTextPane inside a GridBagLayout JPanel. The program adds the the JTextPane in the right place, and everything is fine and dandy until I try to add text to the JTextPane. Then everything goes to hell. No matter what I do or try the JTextPane won't stop resizing itself by a width equal to the longest row and a height equal to the number of rows I'm adding.

This is extremely annoying because it causes all the rest of the Layout to go to hell. (The rest of the Layout is a Grid of rectangles on the main JPanel and another JPanel on the right, contained by the main one containing another grid of rectangles). I COULD use preferred size to stop the culprit from auto-resizing, but that would also prevent it from resizing on a JFrame resize (tip: this == bad).

I was wondering if there is any method involved in the auto-resizing of the JTextPane when text is added I could override to prevent this behaviour.

If it is needed I'll post a snippet later.

Comment: Have you considered using a `JScrollPane`?  If you don't want scroll bars, you can turn them off...

Comment: Wops. I forgot to mention I tried that too and it doesn't work, it will just resize the JScrollPane with it along with ANY number of parents I may assign to it (I tried putting it inside a JScrollPane inside a BorderLayout JPanel inside another BorderLayout JPanel inside the main Panel, just to prove the point. It will still resize no matter what...

Comment: And yes, there is plenty of empty space for it to put the text inside, it just won't use it.

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue somewhere else as `JScrollPane` shouldn't resize because it's contents does, that's the point...

Comment: I don't want it to resize. I want it to stay the size the basic Layout gives it. I don't want it to add more space when adding text (especially cause it makes no sense)

Comment: Sorry, typing to fast, that should read *"shouldn't"* :P